# Nifi - If Else in a jolt

Tags: json, text, apache-nifi

I need to use the field nota_fiscal_operacao with the values "SAIDA" e "ENTRADA" and need to transform in:

Coleta: "True" when  nota_fiscal_operacao = "ENTRADA"
Coleta: "False" when nota_fiscal_operacao = "SAIDA"

Initial Json:

```
[
  {
    "oid_empresa": 1267,
    "oid_transportadora": 29286205,
    "conhecimento_oid_conhecimento": 10855404876,
    "conhecimento_dm_tipo_conhecimento": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido_contribuinte": null,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido": null,
    "pre_nota_oid": null,
    "pre_nota_numero": null,
    "pre_nota_serie": null,
    "ge_codempresa": "014",
    "ge_deposito": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "embarque_oid_empresa": 1267,
    "embarque_oid_embarque": 2227461,
    "embarque_numero": 2227461,
    "embarque_dt_criacao": "2023-04-27 14:02:34.95",
    "embarque_situacao": 0,
    "embarque_form_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "embarque_cep_origem": 13860000,
    "embarque_cep_destino": 14700500,
    "embarque_cidade_origem": "São Paulo",
    "embarque_uf_origem": "SP",
    "embarque_cidade_destomp": "Bebedouro",
    "embarque_uf_destino": "SP",
    "embarque_km_total": null,
    "embarque_km_rodada": null,
    "embarque_produto_predominante": null,
    "embarque_dt_embarque": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_previsao_entrega": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_prazo_cliente": null,
    "embarque_peso": "20.0000",
    "embarque_valor_notas_fiscais": "110.00",
    "embarque_observacao": "Teste Anna Giotto",
    "embarque_trn_cnpj": "45236791013170",
    "embarque_trn_nome": "COOPERCITRUS COOPERATIVA DE PROD RURAIS",
    "embarque_trn_endereco": "AV DR ANTONIO ALVES PASSIG",
    "embarque_trn_numero": "791",
    "embarque_trn_bairro": "RESIDENCIAL E COMERCIAL PALMARES",
    "embarque_trn_contato": null,
    "embarque_trn_telefone": "1639684400",
    "embarque_trn_latitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_longitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_oid_cidade": 3003755,
    "embarque_trn__cidade": "Ribeirão Preto",
    "embarque_trn__euf": "SP",
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_codigo": null,
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_descricao": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_codigo": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_descricao": null,
    "embarque_placa": "MLY4G73",
    "oid_motorista": null,
    "embarque_motorista_cpf": null,
    "embarque_motorista_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_unidade": 13839,
    "nova_fiscal_freteporconta": "0",
    "nota_fiscal_oid_nota_fiscal": 8767938320,
    "nota_fiscal_num_nota_fiscal": 1400,
    "nota_fiscal_serie": "1",
    "nota_fiscal_situacao": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_cfop": null,
    "nota_fiscal_val_mercadoria": "10.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_peso": "10.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_pesocubado": "0.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_qtde_vols": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_dataemissao": "2023-04-27 14:00:31.0",
    "nota_fiscal_chave_acesso_nfe": "41221051775690000191550010001400331220280180",
    "nota_fiscal_ordem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_data_chegada": null,
    "nota_filscal_data_saida": null,
    "nota_fiscal_quilometragem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_tempo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "nota_fiscal_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "nota_fiscal_tp_tipooperacao": 0,
    "nota_fiscal_operacao": "SAIDA",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_pessoa": 4091034321,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cnpj": "45236791004774",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nome": "C047",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_endereco": "RUA JOSE MARRICHI",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nro_endereco": "191",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_bairro": "JARDIM CENTER CITY",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_contato": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_telefone": "1936529800",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_cidade": 3003268,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cidade": "São Paulo",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_euf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_pessoa": 4090406322,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cnpj": "45236791001406",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nome": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "nota_fiscal_des_endereco": "Avenida Quito Stamato",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nro_endereco": "1415",
    "nota_fiscal_des_bairro": "Centro",
    "nota_fiscal_des_contato": "",
    "nota_fiscal_des_telefone": "",
    "nota_fiscal_des_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_cidade": 3003334,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cidade": "Bebedouro",
    "nota_fiscal_des_uf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_produto_codigo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_quantidade": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_peso": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_valor": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_volumes": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_cubagem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_pesocubado": null,
    "nota_fiscal_observacao": ""
  },
  {
    "oid_empresa": 1267,
    "oid_transportadora": 29286205,
    "conhecimento_oid_conhecimento": 10855404918,
    "conhecimento_dm_tipo_conhecimento": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido_contribuinte": null,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido": null,
    "pre_nota_oid": null,
    "pre_nota_numero": null,
    "pre_nota_serie": null,
    "ge_codempresa": "014",
    "ge_deposito": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "embarque_oid_empresa": 1267,
    "embarque_oid_embarque": 2227461,
    "embarque_numero": 2227461,
    "embarque_dt_criacao": "2023-04-27 14:02:34.95",
    "embarque_situacao": 0,
    "embarque_form_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "embarque_cep_origem": 13860000,
    "embarque_cep_destino": 14700500,
    "embarque_cidade_origem": "São Paulo",
    "embarque_uf_origem": "SP",
    "embarque_cidade_destomp": "Bebedouro",
    "embarque_uf_destino": "SP",
    "embarque_km_total": null,
    "embarque_km_rodada": null,
    "embarque_produto_predominante": null,
    "embarque_dt_embarque": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_previsao_entrega": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_prazo_cliente": null,
    "embarque_peso": "20.0000",
    "embarque_valor_notas_fiscais": "110.00",
    "embarque_observacao": "Teste Anna Giotto",
    "embarque_trn_cnpj": "45236791013170",
    "embarque_trn_nome": "COOPERCITRUS COOPERATIVA DE PROD RURAIS",
    "embarque_trn_endereco": "AV DR ANTONIO ALVES PASSIG",
    "embarque_trn_numero": "791",
    "embarque_trn_bairro": "RESIDENCIAL E COMERCIAL PALMARES",
    "embarque_trn_contato": null,
    "embarque_trn_telefone": "1639684400",
    "embarque_trn_latitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_longitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_oid_cidade": 3003755,
    "embarque_trn__cidade": "Ribeirão Preto",
    "embarque_trn__euf": "SP",
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_codigo": null,
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_descricao": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_codigo": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_descricao": null,
    "embarque_placa": "MLY4G73",
    "oid_motorista": null,
    "embarque_motorista_cpf": null,
    "embarque_motorista_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_unidade": 13839,
    "nova_fiscal_freteporconta": "0",
    "nota_fiscal_oid_nota_fiscal": 8767937957,
    "nota_fiscal_num_nota_fiscal": 1353,
    "nota_fiscal_serie": "1",
    "nota_fiscal_situacao": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_cfop": null,
    "nota_fiscal_val_mercadoria": "100.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_peso": "10.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_pesocubado": "0.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_qtde_vols": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_dataemissao": "2023-04-27 13:52:09.0",
    "nota_fiscal_chave_acesso_nfe": "4122105177569000019155001000135331220280180",
    "nota_fiscal_ordem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_data_chegada": null,
    "nota_filscal_data_saida": null,
    "nota_fiscal_quilometragem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_tempo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "nota_fiscal_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "nota_fiscal_tp_tipooperacao": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_operacao": "ENTRADA",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_pessoa": 409040632233333300,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cnpj": "4523679100140666666666",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nome": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_endereco": "Avenida Quito Stamato",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nro_endereco": "1415",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_bairro": "Centro",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_contato": "",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_telefone": "",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_cidade": 3003334,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cidade": "Bebedouro",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_euf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_pessoa": 4091034321,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cnpj": "45236791004774",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nome": "C047",
    "nota_fiscal_des_endereco": "RUA JOSE MARRICHI",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nro_endereco": "191",
    "nota_fiscal_des_bairro": "JARDIM CENTER CITY",
    "nota_fiscal_des_contato": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_telefone": "1936529800",
    "nota_fiscal_des_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_cidade": 3003268,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cidade": "São Paulo",
    "nota_fiscal_des_uf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_produto_codigo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_quantidade": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_peso": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_valor": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_volumes": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_cubagem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_pesocubado": null,
    "nota_fiscal_observacao": ""
  },
  {
    "oid_empresa": 1267,
    "oid_transportadora": 29286205,
    "conhecimento_oid_conhecimento": 10855404918,
    "conhecimento_dm_tipo_conhecimento": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido_contribuinte": null,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido": null,
    "pre_nota_oid": null,
    "pre_nota_numero": null,
    "pre_nota_serie": null,
    "ge_codempresa": "014",
    "ge_deposito": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "embarque_oid_empresa": 1267,
    "embarque_oid_embarque": 2227461,
    "embarque_numero": 2227461,
    "embarque_dt_criacao": "2023-04-27 14:02:34.95",
    "embarque_situacao": 0,
    "embarque_form_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "embarque_cep_origem": 13860000,
    "embarque_cep_destino": 14700500,
    "embarque_cidade_origem": "São Paulo",
    "embarque_uf_origem": "SP",
    "embarque_cidade_destomp": "Bebedouro",
    "embarque_uf_destino": "SP",
    "embarque_km_total": null,
    "embarque_km_rodada": null,
    "embarque_produto_predominante": null,
    "embarque_dt_embarque": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_previsao_entrega": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_prazo_cliente": null,
    "embarque_peso": "20.0000",
    "embarque_valor_notas_fiscais": "110.00",
    "embarque_observacao": "Teste Anna Giotto",
    "embarque_trn_cnpj": "45236791013170",
    "embarque_trn_nome": "COOPERCITRUS COOPERATIVA DE PROD RURAIS",
    "embarque_trn_endereco": "AV DR ANTONIO ALVES PASSIG",
    "embarque_trn_numero": "791",
    "embarque_trn_bairro": "RESIDENCIAL E COMERCIAL PALMARES",
    "embarque_trn_contato": null,
    "embarque_trn_telefone": "1639684400",
    "embarque_trn_latitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_longitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_oid_cidade": 3003755,
    "embarque_trn__cidade": "Ribeirão Preto",
    "embarque_trn__euf": "SP",
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_codigo": null,
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_descricao": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_codigo": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_descricao": null,
    "embarque_placa": "MLY4G73",
    "oid_motorista": null,
    "embarque_motorista_cpf": null,
    "embarque_motorista_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_unidade": 13839,
    "nova_fiscal_freteporconta": "0",
    "nota_fiscal_oid_nota_fiscal": 8767937957,
    "nota_fiscal_num_nota_fiscal": 155555,
    "nota_fiscal_serie": "3",
    "nota_fiscal_situacao": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_cfop": null,
    "nota_fiscal_val_mercadoria": "100.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_peso": "10.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_pesocubado": "0.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_qtde_vols": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_dataemissao": "2023-04-27 13:52:09.0",
    "nota_fiscal_chave_acesso_nfe": "4122105177569000019155001000135331220280180",
    "nota_fiscal_ordem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_data_chegada": null,
    "nota_filscal_data_saida": null,
    "nota_fiscal_quilometragem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_tempo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "nota_fiscal_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "nota_fiscal_tp_tipooperacao": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_operacao": "ENTRADA",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_pessoa": 409040632233333300,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cnpj": "4523679100140666666666",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nome": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_endereco": "Avenida Quito Stamato",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nro_endereco": "1415",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_bairro": "Centro",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_contato": "",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_telefone": "",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_cidade": 3003334,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cidade": "Bebedouro",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_euf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_pessoa": 4091034321,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cnpj": "45236791004774",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nome": "C047",
    "nota_fiscal_des_endereco": "RUA JOSE MARRICHI",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nro_endereco": "191",
    "nota_fiscal_des_bairro": "JARDIM CENTER CITY",
    "nota_fiscal_des_contato": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_telefone": "1936529800",
    "nota_fiscal_des_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_cidade": 3003268,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cidade": "São Paulo",
    "nota_fiscal_des_uf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_produto_codigo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_quantidade": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_peso": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_valor": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_volumes": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_cubagem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_pesocubado": null,
    "nota_fiscal_observacao": ""
  },
  {
    "oid_empresa": 1267,
    "oid_transportadora": 29286205,
    "conhecimento_oid_conhecimento": 10855404918,
    "conhecimento_dm_tipo_conhecimento": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido_contribuinte": null,
    "nota_fiscal_pedido": null,
    "pre_nota_oid": null,
    "pre_nota_numero": null,
    "pre_nota_serie": null,
    "ge_codempresa": "014",
    "ge_deposito": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "embarque_oid_empresa": 1267,
    "embarque_oid_embarque": 2227461,
    "embarque_numero": 2227461,
    "embarque_dt_criacao": "2023-04-27 14:02:34.95",
    "embarque_situacao": 0,
    "embarque_form_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "embarque_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "embarque_cep_origem": 13860000,
    "embarque_cep_destino": 14700500,
    "embarque_cidade_origem": "São Paulo",
    "embarque_uf_origem": "SP",
    "embarque_cidade_destomp": "Bebedouro",
    "embarque_uf_destino": "SP",
    "embarque_km_total": null,
    "embarque_km_rodada": null,
    "embarque_produto_predominante": null,
    "embarque_dt_embarque": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_previsao_entrega": "2023-04-28 00:00:00.0",
    "embarque_dt_prazo_cliente": null,
    "embarque_peso": "20.0000",
    "embarque_valor_notas_fiscais": "110.00",
    "embarque_observacao": "Teste Anna Giotto",
    "embarque_trn_cnpj": "45236791013170",
    "embarque_trn_nome": "COOPERCITRUS COOPERATIVA DE PROD RURAIS",
    "embarque_trn_endereco": "AV DR ANTONIO ALVES PASSIG",
    "embarque_trn_numero": "791",
    "embarque_trn_bairro": "RESIDENCIAL E COMERCIAL PALMARES",
    "embarque_trn_contato": null,
    "embarque_trn_telefone": "1639684400",
    "embarque_trn_latitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_longitude": null,
    "embarque_trn_oid_cidade": 3003755,
    "embarque_trn__cidade": "Ribeirão Preto",
    "embarque_trn__euf": "SP",
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_codigo": null,
    "embarque_fluxo_transporte_descricao": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_codigo": null,
    "embarque_tipo_viagem_descricao": null,
    "embarque_placa": "MLY4G73",
    "oid_motorista": null,
    "embarque_motorista_cpf": null,
    "embarque_motorista_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_unidade": 13839,
    "nova_fiscal_freteporconta": "0",
    "nota_fiscal_oid_nota_fiscal": 8767937957,
    "nota_fiscal_num_nota_fiscal": 156666,
    "nota_fiscal_serie": "1",
    "nota_fiscal_situacao": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_cfop": null,
    "nota_fiscal_val_mercadoria": "100.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_peso": "10.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_pesocubado": "0.0000",
    "nota_fiscal_qtde_vols": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_dataemissao": "2023-04-27 13:52:09.0",
    "nota_fiscal_chave_acesso_nfe": "4122105177569000019155001000135331220280180",
    "nota_fiscal_ordem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_data_chegada": null,
    "nota_filscal_data_saida": null,
    "nota_fiscal_quilometragem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_tempo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_cd_forma_negociacao": 0,
    "nota_fiscal_forma_negociacao": "CIF",
    "nota_fiscal_tp_tipooperacao": 1,
    "nota_fiscal_operacao": "SAIDA",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_pessoa": 409040632233333300,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cnpj": "4523679100140666666666",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nome": "COOPERCITRUS CD 014",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_endereco": "Avenida Quito Stamato",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_nro_endereco": "1415",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_bairro": "Centro",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_contato": "",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_telefone": "",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_oid_cidade": 3003334,
    "nota_fiscal_rem_cidade": "Bebedouro",
    "nota_fiscal_rem_euf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_pessoa": 4091034321,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cnpj": "45236791004774",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nome": "C047",
    "nota_fiscal_des_endereco": "RUA JOSE MARRICHI",
    "nota_fiscal_des_nro_endereco": "191",
    "nota_fiscal_des_bairro": "JARDIM CENTER CITY",
    "nota_fiscal_des_contato": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_telefone": "1936529800",
    "nota_fiscal_des_latitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_longitude": null,
    "nota_fiscal_des_oid_cidade": 3003268,
    "nota_fiscal_des_cidade": "São Paulo",
    "nota_fiscal_des_uf": "SP",
    "nota_fiscal_produto_codigo": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_nome": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_quantidade": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_peso": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_valor": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_volumes": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_cubagem": null,
    "nota_fiscal_produto_pesocubado": null,
    "nota_fiscal_observacao": ""
  }
]
```

Jolt spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": "@embarque_numero[]"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "@": "[]"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@nota_fiscal_des_cnpj[]"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "@nota_fiscal_num_nota_fiscal[]"
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "ge_codempresa": "Empresa",
          "embarque_numero": "Rotas.Codigo",
          "embarque_observacao": "Rotas.Observacao",
          "ge_deposito": "Rotas.Deposito.Nome",
          "nota_fiscal_ordem": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Sequencia",
          "nota_fiscal_quilometragem": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].DistanciaPrevista",
          "nota_fiscal_data_chegada": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].DataChegadaPrevista",
          "nota_filscal_data_saida": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].DataPartidaPrevista",
          "pre_nota_numero": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].Codigo",
          "nota_fiscal_num_nota_fiscal": [
                        "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].CodigoPed",
                        "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].Numero"
                    ],
          "nota_fiscal_operacao": {
            "ENTRADA": {
              "#true": "Rotas.Entregas[#4].Coleta",
              "@(2,nota_fiscal_rem_endereco)": "Rotas.Entregas[#4].Cliente.Endereco",
              "@(2,nota_fiscal_rem_oid_pessoa)": "Rotas.Entregas[&3].Cliente.Codigo",
              "@(2,nota_fiscal_rem_nome)": "Rotas.Entregas[&3].Cliente.Nome",
              "@(2,nota_fiscal_rem_bairro)": "Rotas.Entregas[#4].Cliente.Bairro",
              "@(2,nota_fiscal_rem_cidade)": "Rotas.Entregas[#4].Cliente.Cidade",
              "@(2,nota_fiscal_rem_uf)": "Rotas.Entregas[#4].Cliente.Estado",
              "@(2,nota_fiscal_rem_cnpj)": "Rotas.Entregas[#4].Cliente.Documento"
            }
          },
          "nota_fiscal_des_endereco": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Cliente.Endereco",
          "nota_fiscal_des_oid_pessoa": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Cliente.Codigo",
          "nota_fiscal_des_nome": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Cliente.Nome",
          "nota_fiscal_des_bairro": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Cliente.Bairro",
          "nota_fiscal_des_cidade": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Cliente.Cidade",
          "nota_fiscal_des_uf": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Cliente.Estado",
          "nota_fiscal_des_cnpj": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Cliente.Documento",
          "nota_fiscal_observacao": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].Observacao",
          "nota_fiscal_val_mercadoria": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].Valor",
          "nota_fiscal_qtde_vols": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].Volume",
          "nota_fiscal_peso": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].Peso",
          "nota_fiscal_serie": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].Serie",
          "nota_fiscal_rem_cnpj": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].Documento",
          "nota_fiscal_produto_codigo": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].NotaFiscalItens[#2].Produto.Codigo",
          "nota_fiscal_produto_nome": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].NotaFiscalItens[#2].Produto.Nome",
          "nota_fiscal_produto_quantidade": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].NotaFiscalItens[#2].Quantidade",
          "nota_fiscal_produto_valor": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].NotaFiscalItens[#2].Valor",
          "nota_fiscal_produto_peso": "Rotas.Entregas[#3].Pedidos[#4].NotasFiscais[#4].NotaFiscalItens[#2].Peso"
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "cardinality",
    "spec": {
      "Empresa": "ONE",
      "Rotas": {
        "Codigo": "ONE",
        "DistanciaTotalPrevista": "ONE",
        "DataChegadaPrevista": "ONE",
        "PlacaVeiculo": "ONE",
        "Observacao": "ONE",
        "Transportadora": {
          "Nome": "ONE",
          "Documento": "ONE"
        },
        "Deposito": {
          "Codigo": "ONE",
          "Nome": "ONE"
        },
        "Motorista": {
          "Codigo": "ONE",
          "Documento": "ONE",
          "Nome": "ONE"
        },
        "Entregas": {
          "*": {
            "*": "ONE",
            "Cliente": {
              "*": "ONE"
            },
            "Pedidos": {
              "*": {
                "CodigoPed": "ONE",
                "Codigo": "ONE",
                "NotasFiscais": {
                  "*": {
                    "Numero": "ONE",
                    "TipoOperacao": "ONE",
                    "Observacao": "ONE",
                    "Valor": "ONE",
                    "Volume": "ONE",
                    "Peso": "ONE",
                    "Serie": "ONE",
                    "Documento": "ONE"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Rotas": {
        "Codigo": "=toString",
        "Entregas": {
          "*": {
            "Cliente": {
              "Codigo": "=toString",
              "Bairro": "=substring(@(1,Bairro),0,50)"
            },
            "DistanciaPrevista": [
                            "=toDouble",
                            0
                        ],
            "Sequencia": [
                            "=toInteger",
                            0
                        ],
            "Pedidos": {
              "*": {
                "Codigo": [
                                    "=toInteger",
                                    "@(1,CodigoPed)"
                                ],
                "NotasFiscais": {
                  "*": {
                    "Numero": "=toString",
                    "Valor": [
                                            "=toDouble",
                                            0
                                        ],
                    "Peso": [
                                            "=toDouble",
                                            0
                                        ],
                    "NotaFiscalItens": {
                      "*": {
                        "Peso": [
                                                    "=toDouble",
                                                    0
                                                ],
                        "Valor": [
                                                    "=toDouble",
                                                    0
                                                ],
                        "Quantidade": [
                                                    "=toDouble",
                                                    0
                                                ],
                        "Produto": {
                          "Codigo": "=substring(@(1,Codigo),0,20)",
                          "Nome": "=substring(@(1,Nome),0,100)"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "Rotas": {
        "NomeRota": "${rotaNomeRota:unescapeJson()}",
        "DataChegadaPrevista": "${rotaPrevisaoEntrega:unescapeJson()}",
        "DataPartidaPrevista": "${rotaPrevisaoEntrega:unescapeJson()}",
        "DistanciaTotalPrevista": "${rotaKmTotal:unescapeJson()}",
        "DataRota": "${rotaPrevisaoEntrega:unescapeJson()}",
        "CodigoDispositivoTemperatura": 0,
        "Tipo": "${rotaTipoOperacao:unescapeJson()}",
        "PlacaVeiculo": "${rotaPlaca:unescapeJson()}",
        "Deposito": {
          "Codigo": "${rotaDeposito:unescapeJson()}"
        },
        "Transportadora": {
          "Nome": "${rotaTransportadoraNome:unescapeJson()}",
          "Documento": "${rotaTransportadoraCnpj:unescapeJson()}"
        },
        "Motorista": {
          "Codigo": "${rotaMotoristaCodigo:unescapeJson()}",
          "Documento": "${rotaMotoristaCPF:unescapeJson()}",
          "Nome": "${rotaMotoristaNome:unescapeJson()}"
        },
        "Entregas[]": {
          "*": {
            "Coleta": false,
            "Prateleira": "Prateleira Padrao",
            "Cliente": {
              "Tipo": 1,
              "Telefone": "",
              "CEP": "${cepDestino:unescapeJson()}"
            },
            "Pedidos[]": {
              "*": {
                "NotasFiscais[]": {
                  "*": {
                    "CondicaoPagamento": "PADRAO",
                    "NotaFiscalItens[]": {
                      "*": {
                        "Unidade": "UN",
                        "TipoProduto": {
                          "Codigo": "1",
                          "Descricao": "Diversos"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": "=recursivelySquashNulls"
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "remove",
    "spec": {
      "Rotas": {
        "Entregas": {
          "*": {
            "Pedidos": {
              "*": {
                "CodigoPed": ""
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    },
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "Rotas": {
        "Entregas": {
          "*": {
            "Cliente": {
              "Telefone": "=toString"
            },
            "Pedidos": {
              "*": {
                "Codigo": "=toString"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
]
```

[image: I need a array "Entregas" and I need to each 'Entrega' with the field "Coleta"]

Coleta: "True" when nota_fiscal_operacao = "ENTRADA"
Coleta: "False" when nota_fiscal_operacao = "SAIDA"

For each entrega in a array.

Comment: Well, I think the current image is the current output, what's the expected output then?

Comment: Heelo @BarbarosÖzhan, i need the output with "Coleta": "true" or "false" to all the "Entregas", but only the first validation is coming at the json

Comment: Please edit the question by adding such details cleanly, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rodrigo Hajime Himauari ,

Following spec will help you achieve the desired output.

```
 [
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "[&1].&",
        "nota_fiscal_operacao": {
          "SAIDA": {//If nota_fiscal_operacao= Saida then
            "@(2,nota_fiscal_operacao)": "[&3].nota_fiscal_operacao",
            "#False": "[&3].Coleta" //Coleta= False
          },
          "ENTRADA": {//If nota_fiscal_operacao= ENTRADA
            "@(2,nota_fiscal_operacao)": "[&3].nota_fiscal_operacao",
            "#True": "[&3].Coleta"//Coleta= True
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```